# I am building an iOS app and just chose to build the backend using the AWS iOS SDK instead of a BaaS. What extra work have I just created for myself?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

Instead of using a BaaS (Parse, QuickBlox, MobSquad, Kinvey, StackMob), I have decided to build out the backend using the AWS iOS SDK.

The details of the app's communication with the server backend are as following. The application will have a chat feature that will be the main focus of the app. Because of this, there will be varying load on the server, but the backend needs to ensure a low latency no matter the load (elastic). There will be a potential for a very heavy load because of the chat and event-based features of the app.

What extra work have I just created for myself?

Comment: I have edited the question to narrow the scope and believe it meets the requirement in the [dont ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for subjective questions that are allowed. Please remove the hold or comment if you believe it still should be on hold.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on how complex of an application you desire to build and how much backend knowledge you have.

From a very basic standpoint, using Rails, see [this video](http://vimeo.com/34863929). You can do simple things very easily. If you want to do more advanced things, you will be in for a significant time investment. There's a reason entire companies have formed to provide these services.

---